# Error running the command startup.sh in BYOB- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, arm64, flask-login

Running Unbntu 21.10 on a Rasperry Pi4 8gb.
Using Python 3.9.7 ,
**If you need additional information please ask.**
Updated pip as well as the flash login module, neither fixed the issue, reflashed unbuntu and ran the setup multiple times...
Followed “BYOB Installation and Setup Walkthrough” by Malwared on YouTube. any help or suggestions are appreciated

```
stupid@Cunt-desktop:~/byob/web-gui$ sudo python3 run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stupid/byob/web-gui/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from buildyourownbotnet import create_app
  File "/home/stupid/byob/web-gui/buildyourownbotnet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

Getting a cryptonight error as well but help with this is useless if the previos problem isnt fixed and its not all that important.
**Full command execution -**

```
stupid@Cunt-desktop:~/byob/web-gui$ sudo ./startup.sh
[sudo] password for stupid: 
WARNING: This script will install docker AND add it as an apt source.

If you do not want this, please press ctrl + C to cancel the script.

The script will start in 10 seconds.
Running BYOB app setup...
Confirmed Python is installed.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.3.4-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Confirmed Docker is installed.
If you run into issues generating a Windows payload, please uninstall docker and rerun this script
Installing Python packages...
Collecting CMake==3.18.4
  Using cached cmake-3.18.4.tar.gz (28 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cqt0f6xd/cmake_3541d9b007a940038dfa6c8c3c8d60da/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cqt0f6xd/cmake_3541d9b007a940038dfa6c8c3c8d60da/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-kzotr_hx
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cqt0f6xd/cmake_3541d9b007a940038dfa6c8c3c8d60da/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cqt0f6xd/cmake_3541d9b007a940038dfa6c8c3c8d60da/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        from skbuild import setup
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/fe/def6c924b81aa489c2e304bde3a2818824c30d41dcc938f5cb280b611c14/cmake-3.18.4.tar.gz#sha256=40b9a559e4e0dc43ff130a9df2272f495ad73844b395c2b01648efac3d69d34d (from https://pypi.org/simple/cmake/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement CMake==3.18.4
ERROR: No matching distribution found for CMake==3.18.4
Ignoring pypiwin32: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pyHook: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy==1.3.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.3.23)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.2)
Collecting flask_session
  Using cached Flask_Session-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
Collecting flask_wtf
  Using cached Flask_WTF-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting Flask_SQLAlchemy
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting Flask_Login
  Using cached Flask_Login-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Flask_Bcrypt
  Using cached Flask_Bcrypt-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flask_mail
  Using cached Flask_Mail-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (3.0.0)
Collecting mss==3.3.0
  Using cached mss-3.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: WMI==1.4.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyxhook==1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: twilio==6.14.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (6.14.0)
Collecting colorama==0.3.9
  Using cached colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex==3.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (3.8.1)
Collecting py-cryptonight>=0.2.4
  Using cached py_cryptonight-0.3.3.tar.gz (352 kB)
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (39.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyxhook==1.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 13)) (0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 16)) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 16)) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 16)) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from requests==2.20.0->-r requirements.txt (line 16)) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from twilio==6.14.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pysocks in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from twilio==6.14.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from twilio==6.14.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT>=1.4.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from twilio==6.14.0->-r requirements.txt (line 14)) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flask->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flask->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from flask->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flask->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Flask_Bcrypt->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (3.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from flask_mail->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cachelib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flask_session->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.4.1)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.4.58-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (39.0 MB)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.3.56-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (34.2 MB)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.2.54-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (34.9 MB)
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.1.48-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (34.5 MB)
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.46.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
  Using cached opencv_python-4.4.0.44-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: py-cryptonight
  Building wheel for py-cryptonight (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-6mzbzodb
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/
  Complete output (32 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight
  copying pycryptonight/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
  copying pycryptonight/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
  copying pycryptonight/tests/test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
  running egg_info
  writing py_cryptonight.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to py_cryptonight.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to py_cryptonight.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to py_cryptonight.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'py_cryptonight.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'py_cryptonight.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-fast.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-1.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-2.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-4.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
  running build_ext
  building '_pycryptonight' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src/cryptonight
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DNO_JIT=1 -I. -Isrc/ -Isrc/cryptonight -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/cryptonight/CryptonightR_JIT.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src/cryptonight/CryptonightR_JIT.o -std=gnu11 -maes
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-maes’
  error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for py-cryptonight
  Running setup.py clean for py-cryptonight
Failed to build py-cryptonight
Installing collected packages: py-cryptonight, opencv-python, mss, flask-wtf, Flask-SQLAlchemy, flask-session, flask-mail, Flask-Login, Flask-Bcrypt, colorama
    Running setup.py install for py-cryptonight ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7da8br74/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/py-cryptonight
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/
    Complete output (32 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight
    copying pycryptonight/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
    copying pycryptonight/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
    copying pycryptonight/tests/test.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests
    running egg_info
    writing py_cryptonight.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to py_cryptonight.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to py_cryptonight.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to py_cryptonight.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'py_cryptonight.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'py_cryptonight.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-fast.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-1.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-2.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow-4.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    copying pycryptonight/tests/data/tests-slow.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/pycryptonight/tests/data
    running build_ext
    building '_pycryptonight' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src/cryptonight
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DNO_JIT=1 -I. -Isrc/ -Isrc/cryptonight -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/cryptonight/CryptonightR_JIT.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.9/src/cryptonight/CryptonightR_JIT.o -std=gnu11 -maes
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-maes’
    error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l342gupt/py-cryptonight_2857b58f21124294a87965ecd0c03fa2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7da8br74/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/py-cryptonight Check the logs for full command output.
Building Docker images - this will take a while, please be patient...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.33kB
Step 1/12 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> d5ca7a445605
Step 2/12 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-i", "-c"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b9a918f4f65
Step 3/12 : ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80163281c06b
Step 4/12 : ARG PYINSTALLER_VERSION=3.6
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9aa590097bf8
Step 5/12 : ENV PYPI_URL=https://pypi.python.org/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 212c73774106
Step 6/12 : ENV PYPI_INDEX_URL=https://pypi.python.org/simple
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66df3b36a3c2
Step 7/12 : ENV PYENV_VERSION=${PYTHON_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9e344a4a9638
Step 8/12 : COPY entrypoint-linux.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7eeacb00cf9a
Step 9/12 : RUN     set -x     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         build-essential         ca-certificates         curl         wget         git         libbz2-dev         libreadline-dev         libsqlite3-dev         libssl-dev         zlib1g-dev         libffi-dev         libgdbm-dev         uuid-dev         upx     && mkdir openssl     && cd openssl     && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz     && tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz     && cd openssl-1.1.1h     && ./config --prefix=$HOME/openssl --openssldir=$HOME/openssl shared zlib     && make     && make install     && echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc     && echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc     && source ~/.bashrc     && curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash     && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.bashrc     && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc     && source ~/.bashrc     && PATH="$HOME/openssl:$PATH"  CPPFLAGS="-O2 -I$HOME/openssl/include" CFLAGS="-I$HOME/openssl/include/" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/openssl/lib" LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_RUN_PATH="$HOME/openssl/lib" CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$HOME/openssl" PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install $PYTHON_VERSION     && pyenv global $PYTHON_VERSION     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip install pyinstaller==$PYINSTALLER_VERSION     && mkdir /src/     && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in f5e06a869d87
failed to create endpoint competent_jang on network bridge: failed to add the host (vethb24d8c2) <=> sandbox (veth558d0ee) pair interfaces: operation not supported
Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.33kB
Step 1/12 : FROM i386/ubuntu:18.04
 ---> b44056bbf2d5
Step 2/12 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-i", "-c"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b4eb242eb434
Step 3/12 : ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b688c08d250
Step 4/12 : ARG PYINSTALLER_VERSION=3.6
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cc7873b5dfe
Step 5/12 : ENV PYPI_URL=https://pypi.python.org/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dcc0e90bf8b1
Step 6/12 : ENV PYPI_INDEX_URL=https://pypi.python.org/simple
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df7cb5a265cc
Step 7/12 : ENV PYENV_VERSION=${PYTHON_VERSION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c4f19026cd1e
Step 8/12 : COPY entrypoint-linux.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d34aaaed38a
Step 9/12 : RUN     set -x     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         build-essential         ca-certificates         curl         wget         git         libbz2-dev         libreadline-dev         libsqlite3-dev         libssl-dev         zlib1g-dev         libffi-dev         libgdbm-dev         uuid-dev         upx     && mkdir openssl     && cd openssl     && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz     && tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz     && cd openssl-1.1.1h     && ./Configure linux-generic32 --prefix=$HOME/openssl --openssldir=$HOME/openssl shared zlib     && make     && make install     && echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc     && echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc     && source ~/.bashrc     && curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash     && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc     && source ~/.bashrc     && PATH="$HOME/openssl:$PATH"  CPPFLAGS="-O2 -I$HOME/openssl/include" CFLAGS="-I$HOME/openssl/include/" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/openssl/lib" LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_RUN_PATH="$HOME/openssl/lib" CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$HOME/openssl" PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install $PYTHON_VERSION     && pyenv global $PYTHON_VERSION     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip install pyinstaller==$PYINSTALLER_VERSION     && mkdir /src/     && chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
 ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/386) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
 ---> Running in 2b2f9ceff30f
failed to create endpoint ecstatic_grothendieck on network bridge: failed to add the host (veth4c42bc8) <=> sandbox (veth53c8c1a) pair interfaces: operation not supported
Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.33kB
Step 1/30 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> d5ca7a445605
Step 2/30 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e9aecfd1ea5
Step 3/30 : ARG WINE_VERSION=winehq-stable
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 893054a2d294
Step 4/30 : ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6fe3d714fc10
Step 5/30 : ARG PYINSTALLER_VERSION=3.6
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a70fda166bc0
Step 6/30 : RUN set -x     && dpkg --add-architecture i386     && apt-get update -qy     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -qfy gpg-agent rename apt-transport-https software-properties-common winbind cabextract wget curl zip unzip xvfb xdotool x11-utils xterm     && wget -nv https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key     && apt-key add winehq.key     && add-apt-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'     && apt-get update -qy     && apt-get install --install-recommends -qfy $WINE_VERSION     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && wget -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks     && chmod +x winetricks     && mv winetricks /usr/local/bin
 ---> Running in 914ce300563f
failed to create endpoint cool_blackwell on network bridge: failed to add the host (vethe3bba50) <=> sandbox (vethc1e2f77) pair interfaces: operation not supported
To use some Byob features, you must reboot your system. If this is not your first time running this script, please answer no. Reboot now? [Y/n]: n
Running C2 server with locally hosted web app GUI...
Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000 and set up your user to get started.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stupid/byob/web-gui/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from buildyourownbotnet import create_app
  File "/home/stupid/byob/web-gui/buildyourownbotnet/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

Comment: Please review the tags you applied by their description. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
pip3 install -U Flask
```